# how to save 16bit or 32bit single channel depth map to file in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, depth

I want to render a scene with its depth image,but I do not know how to render 16bit or 32bit single channel depth image? I can only save 8bit with 4 channel png image.

Answer (score 0):

[PNGCS](https://github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/pngcs) writes 16bit per channel png files. With some work it can be extended to support 32bit/ch as well.